# how to display another div element next to the first div element horizontally by clicking or hovering? over the first div

Tags: javascript

On clicking or hovering over a div,it should display the another div next to it,like option it must not be vertical like drop down,it must go on horizontally

Comment: Arul, welcome to Stack Overflow. We encourage reproducible questions here, so if you could please post a link to an example of what you have tried, that would help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it, but aligning div horizontally is done using css, it has nothing to do with hover events. Try to understand the below code.

I am showing in 2 ways here

- (div1,div2) using css
- (div3,div4) using javascript

Link: https://github.com/helloritesh000/how-to-display-another-div-element-next-to-the-first-div-element-horizontally-by

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
}

.parent1 .div1{
    background-color: red;
}

.div2{
    background-color: cyan;
    display: none;
}

.parent1 .div:hover + div{
    display: block;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parent1">
    <div class="div div1">
    </div>
    <div class="div div2">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div class="parent2">
    <div class="div div3" id="div3" onmouseover="div4.style.visibility='visible'" onmouseout="div4.style.visibility='hidden'" style="background-color: blue;">
    </div>
    <div class="div div4" id="div4" style="background-color: #ccc;">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
div4.style.visibility='hidden'
</script>
</body>
</html>
```